# Encrypting file in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to encrypt file by adding some int (a key selected randomly) for every char on it .
for instance if the file contain the string "abcde" ,with key=2 
the encrypted string will be "cdefg" 
the problem is that im using the encryption algorithm a lot of time and than im over the ascii table(over 255) .
I tried to think in a way of modulo but it didn't help.
anyone has an idea ?

Comment: A simple substitution cipher doesn't really warrant the 'encryption' tag, or description.

Comment: This is called a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Answer (score 1):

When you go over the ascii table value of 255, wrap it to 0 onwards. Something like:

```
int randomKey = 2; //However you want to assign the value - do it.
...
//This is how you "encrypt" a character. Example character is 'a'.
int character = 'a';
int encryptedChar = character + randomKey;
if (encryptedChar > 255) {
    encryptedChar -= 255;
}
```

When "decrypt"ing follow the reverse logic.

However this is a very weak "encryption". A cryptanalyst will break it in no time!

Also note java char is 16 bit. Value can be more than 255. You should ensure input characters are in the range 0-255. Reject values beyond that.

Comment: The OP mentioned modulo didn't work? `int encryptedChar = (character + randomKey) % 255;` should work fine, and the `if` can be removed.

Comment: By the way, this is a very weak encrypting algorithm. You should think of stronger algorithms, such as Rijindael.

Comment: The modulo won't work because one of the algorithms is the multiple the value of the char  in the  key.
but if i'm adding he key it shoul work fine.